# Audio file looping in p5js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

First I just want to say thank you to everyone that has been helping me on this site. It's really helping my confidence with javascript.

I am building an audio/visual app that should play a different sound every time the user clicks. Every time the user clicks, the animation restarts as well and so on. My issue is that I plan on inserting 5-10 sounds that I have designed myself and I would like them to loop with every click. Meaning click once, soun1 plays. Click again, sound 2 plays. So in my mind, I should create a for loop with an array of the sounds. Simple idea, but I have no idea how to do this in vanilla js let alone p5. I'm working with p5 because I might want to add audio effects later on. Anyway, this is what I have tried below. I can play a single sound just fine, and feel like I am on the right track, but I keep getting errors like .play() is not defined.

I know the syntax below is wayyyy off in the loop area. I just started throwing everything at the wall.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="resources\p5.js"></script>
    <script src="resources\p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="resources\p5.sound.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
    <title>Breathe</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>



    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    } 



    let outerDiam = 0;
    let cnv;
    let px;
    let py;
    let bgColor;
    let sound1;
    let sound2;
    let sound3;
    let sound4;
    let sound5;
    let allSounds;

    function centerCanvas() {
      let x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
      let y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
      cnv.position(x, y);
    }

    function setup() { 
      sound1 = loadSound('https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hkg7jnhfwic842j/bubbles.mp3?dl=0', loaded);
      sound2 = loadSound('https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9el41r25exizbwl/clay.mp3?dl=0', loaded);
      sound3 = loadSound('https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8o5rgfknx0do8ps/confetti.mp3?dl=0', loaded);
      sound4 = loadSound('https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/g5auzxd6lkk522a/corona.mp3?dl=0', loaded);
      sound5 = loadSound('https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/pc73ig27wmmnc4l/dotted-spiral.mp3?dl=0', loaded);
      cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
      cnv.style('display', 'block');
      centerCanvas();
      bgColor = random(150, 255);
    } 

    function loaded() {
      console.log('song is loaded');
    }

    function windowResized() {
      centerCanvas();
    }

    function draw() { 
      background(bgColor);
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        let diam = outerDiam - 30 * i;  
      if (diam > 0) {
        let fade = map(diam, 0, width, 0, 255);
          stroke(fade);
          noFill();
          ellipse(px, py, diam);
      }
    } 
        outerDiam = outerDiam + 2;
    }

    function mousePressed() {
      outerDiam = 0;
      px = random(width);
      py = random(height);
      bgColor = random (150, 255);

    //  if (!sound1.isPlaying()) {
    //     sound1.play();
    //     sound1.play();
    // } else {
    //     sound1.pause();
    // }
     allSounds = [sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4, sound5];
     let newSound = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < allSounds.length; i++) {
       allSounds[i].push(newSound);
       allSounds[i].play();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Fix you code example or better create code snippet.

Comment: not quite sure how to do so. It just lumps everything together when I try.

Answer (score 0):

Not a P5 expert, but you can do this using plain Javascript, using the `Audio` class:

```
var audio = new Audio("path/to/audio");
audio.loop = true; //loop
audio.play(); //play
```

Then, whenever you want to change track:

```
audio.pause(); //stop playing old track
audio.currentTime = 0; //rewind
audio.src = "path/to/new_track" //change track
audio.play() //play
```

Comment: thanks for this. Yea If I can't figure it out with the p5 library, I'll try with vanilla. Problem is, I won't have access to the audio effects.

Comment: also, should I put all of this into a separate click function? would this work in conjunction with the animation?